# Kotlin Spring: Unresolved reference method

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have the following class in file A:

```
@Service
class MyService(
  private val myLoader: Loader
) {

  fun load(myKey: SomeKey) =
    myLoader.loadStuff(myKey)
}
```

I want to call that function in another file B like so:

```
MyService.load(myKey)
```

However, the load() method is marked red in IntelliJ. The error says "Unresolved reference: load" and I can't figure out why. When I type `MyService.` IntelliJ even suggests the load method.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you need an instance of a class in order to access a function of that class. In spring (which you should probably tag, or at least mention in the question) you do that by autowiring it in the place where you need to use it. Making the function static (moving it to a companion object) won't help because you need to access `myLoader` which is a property of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, the other component that should call `MyService` must also be a Spring-managed Bean so that it can get a hold of the `MyService` bean. Your component in the file B should look as follows:

```kotlin
@Service
class MyServiceB (
  private val myService: MyService
) {

  fun test(myKey: SomeKey) = myService.load(myKey)
}
```

Mind the `@Service` annotation that makes it a Spring-managed Bean and also the fact that `MyService` is an argument of `MyServiceB` constructor, telling Spring that a Bean of type `MyService` must be injected.

---

Given that you have an object instead of a class, you will have to do something like the following:

```kotlin
object MyServiceB (
  lateinit var myService: MyService
) {

  fun test(myKey: SomeKey) = myService.load(myKey)
}
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MyServiceBConfiguration(private val myService: MyService) {

    @Bean
    fun myServiceB(): MyServiceB {
        return MyServiceB.also {
            it.myService = myService
        }
    }
}
```

This should work but I definitely do not recommend it. This is a hack and definitely not a clean solution. Consider my initial suggestion.

Comment: Any reason for using object? That creates a singleton object.

Comment: @inconnu, did this help in any way?